# error al agregar mas campos a formulario de registro

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Buen día, estoy probando un registro, y me da error al añadirle más campos, actualmente tiene solo el de usuario y contraseña, pero quiero añadirle 7 campos más, ya intente añadirle 1 y me dio error, entonces no se donde tendria el error, el codigo que dejo aqui es el funcional solo con el de usuario y contraseña, me gustaria saber como duplico de forma correcta el validar usuario para agregar el campo de correo, y a la vez agregar 6 campos extras de informacion, como por ejemplo: direccion, telefono, etc. Ayuda?

Actualizo el codigo con el formulario email, y me marca el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_stmt_close(): Argument #1
> ($statement) must be of type mysqli_stmt, bool given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login-php\register.php:42 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login-php\register.php(42): mysqli_stmt_close(false)
> #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login-php\register.php on line 42

````
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $email = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $email_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Por favor ingrese un usuario.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "Este usuario ya fue tomado.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Al parecer algo salió mal.";
            }
        }
         
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    
    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Por favor ingresa una contraseña.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "La contraseña al menos debe tener 6 caracteres.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Confirma tu contraseña.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "No coincide la contraseña.";
        }
    }

    // Validate email
    if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
        $email_err = "Por favor ingresa un email.";
    } else{
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    }
    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Algo salió mal, por favor inténtalo de nuevo.";
            }
        }
         
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Registro</h2>
        <p>Por favor complete este formulario para crear una cuenta.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Usuario</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Confirmar Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ingresar">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Borrar">
            </div>
            <p>¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="login.php">Ingresa aquí</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Agrega el error que te lanza para tener más contexto

Comment: listo, ya subi el error y actualice lo que estaba probando, buen dia, agradecido de ante mano si puede ayudarme

Comment: Ahorita te debe marcar error por que en tu INSERT le especificas 3 columnas pero en tus values solo tienes dos parámetros deberia ser `INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`, al igual en `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, debes especificar adicional el parámetro de email y en `//Set parámetros`, asignarlo

Comment: ya coloque el value, el tercer value y el param y me da el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

En este bloque de código encontré un error que mencionaban en los comentarios. Aparentemente funciona todo bien. Busqué reproducir tu error y le coloqué  `printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));` para ver qué puede pasar. Te recomiendo que lo pongas como te describo y puede darte otra pista. Puede ser que el password sea demasiado largo y no te deje guardarlo en la tabla.

```
 // Check input errors before inserting in database
if(empty($username_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
    
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
     
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username, $email, $param_password);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: login.php");
        } else{
             //Obtener error
             printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
            echo "Algo salió mal, por favor inténtalo de nuevo.";
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```